# Keras model pyspark error

Tags: pyspark, keras, pickle

I have a keras model that has been pickled as described in the following blog.

http://zachmoshe.com/2017/04/03/pickling-keras-models.html

What's strange is that, when I ran the model on an html file when read from python as open(filename), it worked as expected. But when running it on a file when read from pyspark, I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError("'Model' object has no attribute '_feed_input_names'",)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to run `make_keras_picklable()` on each worker as well. Otherwise, the `__setstate__` method of `Model` object on worker node is not updated and thus will not be deserialized as expected.