# Pickling monkey-patched Keras model for use in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, keras, pickle, monkeypatching

The overall goal of what I am trying to achieve is sending a Keras model to each spark worker so that I can use the model within a UDF applied to a column of a DataFrame. To do this, the Keras model will need to be picklable.

It seems like a lot of people have had success at pickling keras models by monkey patching the Model class as shown by the link below:

http://zachmoshe.com/2017/04/03/pickling-keras-models.html

However, I have not seen any example of how to do this in tandem with Spark. My first attempt just ran the `make_keras_picklable()` function on in the driver which allowed me to pickle and unpickle the model in the driver, but I could not pickle the model in UDFs.

```
def make_keras_picklable():
    "Source: https://zachmoshe.com/2017/04/03/pickling-keras-models.html"
    ...

make_keras_picklable()

model = Sequential() # etc etc

def score(case):
    ....
    score = model.predict(case)
    ...

def scoreUDF = udf(score, ArrayType(FloatType()))
```

The error I get suggests that the unpickling the model in the UDF is not using the monkey-patched Model class.

```
AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_built'
```

It looks like another user was running into similar errors in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46481920/keras-model-pyspark-error) and the answer was to "run `make_keras_picklable()` on each worker as well." No example of how to do this was given.

My question is: What is the appropriate way to call `make_keras_picklable()` on all workers?

I tried using `broadcast()` (see below) but got the same error as above.

```
def make_keras_picklable():
    "Source: https://zachmoshe.com/2017/04/03/pickling-keras-models.html"
    ...

make_keras_picklable()
spark.sparkContext.broadcast(make_keras_picklable())

model = Sequential() # etc etc

def score(case):
    ....
    score = model.predict(case)
    ...

def scoreUDF = udf(score, ArrayType(FloatType()))
```

Comment: You can try to use `pandas_udf` and broadcast just the model weights. Then inside pandas_udf, you build a model and load the weights.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Khaled Zaouk](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=user_nodes&user=9233) over on the Spark user mailing list helped me out by suggesting that the `make_keras_picklable()` be changed to a wrapper class. This worked great!

```
import tempfile

import tensorflow as tf


class KerasModelWrapper:
    """Source: https://zachmoshe.com/2017/04/03/pickling-keras-models.html"""

    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model

    def __getstate__(self):
        model_str = ""
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".hdf5", delete=True) as fd:
            tf.keras.models.save_model(self.model, fd.name, overwrite=True)
            model_str = fd.read()
        d = {"model_str": model_str}
        return d

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".hdf5", delete=True) as fd:
            fd.write(state["model_str"])
            fd.flush()
            self.model = tf.keras.models.load_model(fd.name)
```

Of course this could probably be made a little bit more elegant by implementing this as a subclass of Keras's Model class or maybe a PySpark.ML transformer/estimator.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Are you able to expand on your implementation, I have not been able to get this solution to work.

Comment: @MatthewJackson I am happy to try and help if you have more details on why solution isn't working for you. As far as I remember, for my use case the solution worked exactly as posted.

Comment: I couldn't understand how this should be implemented. I make an instance of the class `KerasModelWrapper(my_model)` but then when I save and load the wrapped model and try to use it I get errors saying no class method predict. I am trying to use the wrapped model as part of a sklearn pipeline.

Comment: @Erp12 can u share a minimum reproducable example? Have some difficulty to make it work.

Comment: @MatthewJackson Let's think about what is this code is actually doing. It isn't defining a new estimator/model. It is storing your model as an attribute of the picklable/serialized `KerasModelWrapper` object. If you want retrieve the model and call `.predict()` you have to reference to `model` attribute of the wrapper. Does that help?

Comment: @MpizosDimitris The code snippet in the solution is the minimum reproducible example. It is not specific to my use case. If you explain what you are having difficulty with, I can clarify further.

Comment: @Erp12 My question was more where you run this on the script. Before you train?after? Do you use it also when you load it? I was unable to run due to I had custom layers in my dl architecture. I know I can pass them through custom_objects in load_model but I was having errors also there. The only way that worked for me is to transform the df to rdd and use mapPartitions, where the model is loaded in each partition so no need to be serialized. But I am really interested to make this work with serialization of keras models.

Comment: @MpizosDimitris Thanks for the clarification. Regarding your question about pre-train or post-train, your answer will depend on the behavior of the keras `save` method/function. According to the [keras docs FAQ](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model) model weights are included when saving so they will be included in our pickled wrapper object. Thus, we can send trained or untrained keras modes and they _should_ be unchanged in our UDFs. But... this pattern of broadcasting models isn't going to give you distributed training, so only use trained models.

Comment: @Erp12 Can you fill in some details about what to broadcast or call after adding this wrapper class? And, it will be great if you can show us how to use this class inside pyspark. Thanks!

Comment: @Erp12 First error: NameError: name 'km' is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

With the same idea of Erp12 , you can use this class to wrap a keras model, creating all its attributes dynamically, with the same spirit of the decorator pattern and extending a keras model, as Erp12 suggested.

```
import tempfile
import tensorflow as tf

class PicklableKerasModel(tf.keras.models.Model):

    def __init__(self, model):
        self._model = model

    def __getstate__(self):
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.hdf5', delete=True) as fd:
            tf.keras.models.save_model(self._model, fd.name, overwrite=True)
            model_str = fd.read()
        d = {'model_str': model_str}
        return d

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.hdf5', delete=True) as fd:
            fd.write(state['model_str'])
            fd.flush()
            model = tf.keras.models.load_model(fd.name)
        self._model = model

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.__dict__['_model'], name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name == '_model':
            self.__dict__['_model'] = value
        else:
            setattr(self.__dict__['_model'], name, value)

    def __delattr__(self, name):
        delattr(self.__dict__['_model'], name)
```

Then you just can use the model wrapping your keras model like:

```
model = Sequential() # etc etc

picklable_model = PicklableKerasModel(model)
```